# UIView animateWithDuration not work with UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to increase width of UISlider in animated way, but after animation completion when trying to use slider.... it go back to it's starting width, which is 0.

in .h

```
UISlider *slider;
```

in .m

viewDidLoad :

```
 slider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 65, 0, 23)];
 [self.view addSubview:slider];
```

and in IBAction

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:1];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
slider.frame=CGRectMake(65, 65, 183, 23);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Use the newer block based `UIView` animation method.

Comment: Try to remove line [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:1]. It is also better to use block methods (Apple documentation about your method - Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) - for example animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Auto Layout is enabled on your ViewController. You might have to turn it off to get the behavior you're expecting.

1. Select the ViewController in the Storyboard or NIB
2. Click the 'File Inspector' tab on the right hand side of your Xcode window
3. Under the 'Interface Builder Document' section, uncheck 'Use Autolayout'

Hopefully that works.

**EDIT**

Okay I think I figured out your problem. A UISlider isn't visible on a view unless its width is greater than 3. I'm assuming you are initializing the UISlider with a width of 0 because you want it to 'appear from nowhere' with animation. You'll have to initialize the UISlider with a width greater than 3 to make it animate. If you're still wanting an 'appear from nowhere' effect, I would set the alpha property of the UISlider to 0 when initialized, and then animate the alpha to 1 in the animation block.

Like this:

viewDidLoad:

```
slider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 65, 4, 23)];
slider.alpha=0;
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

IBAction:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    slider.frame=CGRectMake(65, 65, 183, 23);
    slider.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //write code to be executed when animation is done
}];
```

Comment: This code of block not make slider animated.It shows without animation it will take 0.5 sec. but not showing any animation.It works for other controls like UIButton but not work for UISlider.   plz check this and help me ..........